# django two factor OTP in DRF

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I want to protect one route in a project on DRF, but there are features, an example of implementation that I have not found on the Internet.

The structure of logic is like this bellow

1. Implement Two-Factor Authentication (2FA):
   Integrate a third-party service like Google Authenticator for generating verification codes.
   When a user tries to access the sensitive route, prompt them to enter a verification code along with their credentials.
   Verify the entered code with the code generated by the Google Authenticator or similar service.
2. Email Verification:
   Maintain a list of email addresses that are allowed to access the sensitive route.
   Compare the email address of the authenticated user (request.user.email) with the list of allowed email addresses.
   If the user's email is in the allowed list, send a verification code to their email address.
   Prompt the user to enter the verification code received via email.
   Verify the entered code against the code sent to the user's email.
3. Granting Access:
   If the user successfully completes both steps of authentication (2FA and email verification), grant them access to the sensitive route.
   Otherwise, deny access to the route.

If anyone has encountered a similar implementation, please give me some direction